# PHP Gsuite login and Service accounts

Tags: php, google-authentication, service-accounts

I'm currently testing a PHP script which uses Oauth 2.0 login and some api scopes that i can retrieve logged in user information and group information.
This group information determines the redirection of that user once authorised.

This works fine but some of the api scopes are admin based scopes and only work when i log in.
Ive read about creating a service account and site wide api delegations (Which i have done) but im not sure how to implement this into my test PHP code?

index.php code

```
<?php
//Include Configuration File
include('config.php');

$login_button = '';

//This $_GET["code"] variable value received after user has login into their Google Account redirct to PHP script then this variable value has been received
if(isset($_GET["code"]))
{
//It will Attempt to exchange a code for an valid authentication token.
$token = $google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET["code"]);
//This condition will check there is any error occur during geting authentication token. If there is no any error occur then it will execute if block of code/
if(!isset($token['error']))
{
//Set the access token used for requests
$google_client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);
//Store "access_token" value in $_SESSION variable for future use.
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $token['access_token'];
//Create Object of Google Service OAuth 2 class
$google_service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($google_client);
//Get user profile data from google
$data = $google_service->userinfo->get();
//Below you can find Get profile data and store into $_SESSION variable
if(!empty($data['given_name']))
{
$_SESSION['user_first_name'] = $data['given_name'];
}
if(!empty($data['family_name']))
{
$_SESSION['user_last_name'] = $data['family_name'];
}
if(!empty($data['email']))
{
$_SESSION['user_email_address'] = $data['email'];
}
if(!empty($data['gender']))
{
$_SESSION['user_gender'] = $data['gender'];
}
if(!empty($data['picture']))
{
$_SESSION['user_image'] = $data['picture'];
}
}
}
//This is for check user has login into system by using Google account, if User not login into system then it will execute if block of code and make code for display Login link for Login using Google account.
if(!isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
{
 //Create a URL to obtain user authorization
 $login_button = '<a href="'.$google_client->createAuthUrl().'"><img src="sign-in-with-google.png" /></a>';
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PHP Login using Google Account</title>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<br />
<h2 align="center">PHP1 Login using Google Account</h2>
<br />
<div class="panel panel-default">
<?php
if($login_button == '')
{
echo '<div class="panel-heading">Welcome User</div><div class="panel-body">';
echo '<img src="'.$_SESSION["user_image"].'" class="img-responsive img-circle img-thumbnail" />';
echo '<h3><b>Name :</b> '.$_SESSION['user_first_name'].' '.$_SESSION['user_last_name'].'</h3>';
echo '<h3><b>Email :</b> '.$_SESSION['user_email_address'].'</h3>';
echo '<h3><a href="logout.php">Logout</h3></div></a>';
//echo $_SESSION['access_token'];
$gruppen = new Google_Service_Directory($google_client);
$optParams = array('userKey' => $data['id']);
$retGruppen = $gruppen->groups->listGroups($optParams);
//var_dump($gruppen->groups->listGroups($optParams));
$usergrouparray = array($gruppen->groups->listGroups($optParams));
//need to check array key ['name'] if it equals to all staff
//print_r with true converts output to string, we store the string as variable then check that variable to see if it contains All Staff
$test = print_r($usergrouparray,true);
//echo $test ; //prints all array 

if (strpos($test, 'All Staff') !== false) {
echo 'true';
    
} else { echo 'false';}

}
else
{
echo '<div align="center">'.$login_button . '</div>';
}
?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Config.php

```
<?php

//config.php

//Include Google Client Library for PHP autoload file
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

//Make object of Google API Client for call Google API
$google_client = new Google_Client();
//Set the OAuth 2.0 Client ID
$google_client->setClientId('my id');

//Set the OAuth 2.0 Client Secret key
$google_client->setClientSecret('my key');

//Set the OAuth 2.0 Redirect URI
$google_client->setRedirectUri('my redirected uri here');

//
$google_client->addScope('email');
$google_client->addScope('profile');
$google_client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly");
$google_client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user");

//start session on web page
session_start();

?>
```

How do I go about implementing my service account so the above uses this?

Am i going about this the wrong way? I do need to tell what group they are a member of (eg. is staff or not)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve this by creating a new client instance and instigating my service accountjust before wanting the group information

```
$KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/accountkey/client-key.json';

// Create and configure a new client object.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setSubject('admin@yourdomainhere.etc');
$client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
$client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
$client->addScope('email');
$client->addScope('profile');
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user");
$gruppen = new Google_Service_Directory($client);
$optParams = array('userKey' => $data['id']);
$retGruppen = $gruppen->groups->listGroups($optParams);
//var_dump($gruppen->groups->listGroups($optParams));
$usergrouparray = array($gruppen->groups->listGroups($optParams));
```